# How to draw continuous enemies in java 2D

Tags: java, android, applet, 2d

I'm creating a battleship game with a ship at the bottom of the screen moving left and right.
The ship shoots projectiles straight up at bombs dropping from the sky.

The objective is to have a continous flow of bombs dropping down at the player to shoot at and avoid.

So far I have only delt with drawing like this:

```
public static Bomb b1, b2;
private Image image, Battleship, Background, Bomb;


     @Override
            public void start() {
                bg1 = new Background(0, 0);
                ship = new Ship();
                b1 = new Bomb(340, -100);
                b2 = new Bomb(700, -100);
                Thread thread = new Thread(this);
                thread.start();
            }

    @Override
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                ship.update();

                ArrayList projectiles = ship.getProjectiles();
                for(int i = 0; i < projectiles.size(); i++){
                    Projectile p = (Projectile) projectiles.get(i);
                    if(p.isVisible() == true){
                        p.update();
                    }else{
                        projectiles.remove(i);
                    }
                }
                b1.update();
                b2.update();
                bg1.update();
                bg2.update();
                repaint();
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(17);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }

        @Override
            public void paint(Graphics g) {
                g.drawImage(Background, bg1.getBgX(), bg1.getBgY(), this);

                ArrayList projectiles = ship.getProjectiles();
                for(int i = 0; i < projectiles.size(); i++){
                    Projectile p = (Projectile) projectiles.get(i);
                    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                    g.fillRect(p.getX(), p.getY(), 5, 10);
                }
                g.drawImage(Battleship, ship.getCenterX() + 230, ship.getCenterY() -23, this);

                g.drawImage(Bomb, b1.getCenterX() - 20, b1.getCenterY() - 19, this);
                g.drawImage(Bomb, b2.getCenterX() - 20, b2.getCenterY() - 19, this);

                g.setFont(font);
                g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                g.drawString(text, 650, 30);
                g.drawString(Integer.toString(score), 720, 30);
            }
```

So everything i draw is there at the start how would I add bombs continuously?

Comment: create bomb-elements inside your run()-function? depending on how often there should be bombs, you could have a counter on time

Comment: How would that work? would i still have to declare all the bombs? like public static Bomb b1, b2, b3 ... and so on? and how would i make use of a timer to draw a new bomb every 5 seconds for instance? BTW this is my first time making a game :)

Comment: you could put a 
Bomb b = new Bomb(x, y); inside the run(). you could check the time by getting the localtime, and inside an if-statement check if the time is 5sec more than last time
if(timechange > 5){ new bomb }

Comment: Thanks a lot! how would you change the code I have to accomplish this? I would have to import something to get local time I imagine. How would i change my start and paint from what i have now? I see what you are saying I'm just not sure how the code would look like

Comment: put f.e. all your new bombs in an arraylist a (a.add(new bomb)) and then you update all the bombs in the list also inside the run()

Comment: hmm not having any luck implementing this. In run right now i just have the update (b1.update();) wich moves the bombs down 
(public void update(){
speedY = 1;
centerY += speedY;
})

not sure how the final code would look like.

could I change my bomb object to: public static Bomb b; ?
and in run(): b = new Bomb(x, y) 
SOME CODE TO CHECK TIME AND CREATE A NEW BOMB ?

and finally my paint()
g.drawImage(Bomb, b.getCenterX() - 20, b.getCenterY() -19, this)??

Answer (score 0):

What i meant in my comments was something like this:

```
ArrayList bombs;

public void run() {
            while (true) {
                ship.update();

                ArrayList projectiles = ship.getProjectiles();
                for(int i = 0; i < projectiles.size(); i++){
                    Projectile p = (Projectile) projectiles.get(i);
                    if(p.isVisible() == true){
                        p.update();
                    }else{
                        projectiles.remove(i);
                    }
                }

                for(int i=0; i<bombs.size(); i++){

                    Bomb b = bombs.get(i);
                    b.update();
                }

                int timechangeinsec = getTimeChange(); //fix somehow
                if(timechangeinsec > 5){
                    Bomb b = new Bomb(randomx, randomy);
                    bombs.add(b);
                }

                bg1.update();
                bg2.update();
                repaint();
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(17);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
}
```

For the bombs something like this:

```
for(int i=0; i<bombs.size(); i++){
    Bomb b = bombs.get(i);
    g.drawImage(Bomb, b.getCenterX() - 20, b.getCenterY() - 19, this);
}
```

Comment: ok. How would the new bombs that gets added to bomb array get added to game. They would have to be painted in paint() class wouldn't they?

Comment: you could put in the update()-loops a reference for them to get painted. you could also just repaint everything from the arraylist bombs